# Cannot Install Boot Camp on a Mac Fusion Drive

Tags: mac, partitioning, boot-camp, mbr, fusion-drive

I have two drives installed in my MacBoook Pro (Mid-2013). It is running macOS Mavericks (10.9). I set the two drives (an SSD and a regular HD) up using the fusion drive (following the DIY Mac Fusion Drive guides out there).

I went ahead and created a 40GB partition to host my Windows install. I removed the SSD, installed Windows, then reinstalled the SSD. As soon as the SSD was placed back in the Boot Camp partition stopped booting. I get a blinking cursor on a black screen.

I checked out the partition info in Disk Utility and it appears that the Windows partition is not marked bootable. Below is some info I managed to gather.

I am wondering if there is a way to fix the partition table so my Boot Camp will boot.

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *120.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage                         119.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
/dev/disk1
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
   2:       Microsoft Basic Data BOOTCAMP                40.0 GB    disk1s2
   3:          Apple_CoreStorage                         459.2 GB   disk1s3
   4:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               650.0 MB   disk1s4
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           *573.4 GB   disk2
Name :  BOOTCAMP
Type :  Partition

Disk Identifier :   disk1s2
Mount Point :   /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
File System :   Windows NT File System (NTFS)
Connection Bus :    SATA
Device Tree :   IODeviceTree:/PCI0@0/SATA@1F,2/PRT1@1/PMP@0
Writable :  No
Universal Unique Identifier :   584BAED6-4C46-4F18-93B3-957F6E27003C
Capacity :  40 GB (39,998,980,096 Bytes)
Free Space :    16.34 GB (16,339,972,096 Bytes)
Used :  23.66 GB (23,659,003,904 Bytes)
Number of Files :   86,424
Number of Folders :     0
Owners Enabled :    No
Can Turn Owners Off :   No
Can Be Formatted :  No
Bootable :  No
Supports Journaling :   No
Journaled :     No
Disk Number :   1
Partition Number :  2
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, it took me days to work out how to get it working, endlessly trying different ways to get windows running on my Fusion drive using bootcamp on my Mid 2012 15" MacBook Pro.

A little about my set up, originally I bought a 750gb SSHD to replace the stock HDD. After the release of Apples new Fusion Drive I decided to read in on it and realised it was possible to make a DIY Fusion Drive on my MacBook Pro.

So I decided to buy a 250GB Samsung 840 EVO SSD and use the 750GB SSHD as the secondary drive. After installing both drives and creating a fusion drive I came across a problem which was on bootcamp, windows would have trouble installing and booting on the drive configuration in my computer. I have sifted through thousands of threads and what felt like thousands of different methods to get Bootcamp and windows running on a DIY Fusion Drive on my MacBook Pro.

I will not bore you with the different methods I tried, which eventually failed, i'm sure you've been through the same process I have.

How I came to the solution is that I read a totally unrelated thread explaining that windows, for reasons I will never be able to understand will not boot from an external drive, which technically the drive replacing the superdrive is, however MacOSX will boot from any drive. So I thought to myself what if I swap the two drives over? Put my SSD in the secondary drive and use the SSHD as the primary drive. I was concerned about speed issues and whether or not the fusion drive would work, however to my surprise I have seen no issues on my fusion drive or speed issues on the SSD, also windows boots up like a pro!

How I got there.

1. If like me you already have a DIY Fusion Drive set up, the process will be slightly easier. if not, follow the steps to installing a Fusion Drive (Various threads online explain how to do this.)
2. Once you have MacOSX installed on your Fusion Drive start the bootcamp process by getting the necessary iso, partitioning your hard drive etc.
3. Once the files folders and partitioning has finished you don't want to try and install windows yet, it will just fail, or wont work full stop.
4. This is the annoying bit! You will want to take the part of the HDD with the bootcamp partition and make it the primary drive again, you will also want to install the superdrive (dvd drive) back to its original place. (so for me that was putting my SSHD from the superdrive bay to the primary bay and putting the Superdrive back in its original place.)
5. Once that was done I booted up my computer whilst holding alt which produces all the different drives the computer can see installed or connected to my computer. Bootcamp was there along with a MacOSX partition and the USB of Windows. I clicked the USB with Windows and started installing windows on the bootcamp partition. (You may need to partition the Bootcamp drive in the Windows Installer, as sometimes it complains it can't install Windows on it.)
6. After Windows installed successfully I turned my computer off. I then proceeding to remove the Superdrive and putting the SSD in its place.
7. My set up now is the SSHD in the primary slot and the SSD in the secondary slot.
8. I can now boot to Windows and MacOSX perfectly with no problems whatsoever, including the fusion drive. MacOSX still sees it as a single hard drive.

I have no performance issues, or start up from sleep issues in both operating systems. I believe this is due to the fact the MacBook Pro I have has better hardware in the Superdrive port. (Not 100% sure) Both drives have S.M.A.R.T status and I still receive the same read and write speeds on my SSD.

Just a heads up, if you download a hard drive speed test it will start testing the HDD drive because it's in the primary slot. I had to check the speed test of both drives in Terminal, many tutorials online show you how to do this.

As a reminder I have the 15" Mid-2012 Macbook Pro, this set up works flawlessly for me, however I cannot be 100% sure if you will get the same performance from the SSD in the secondary slot as you would from the primary slot if you use this method in older Macbook Pro models.